# SQL Query From two Table satisfying a condition

Tags: sql-server, mysql, mysql-5.5

```
Table 1 name: Student
Name      Department
Alex         CSE
Bob          EEE
Briyan       ME
John         CSE
James        ETE
Mike         CE

Table 2 name: Program
Department    Semester
   CSE         Summer
   CSE         Winter
   EEE         Summer
   ETE         Summer
   ME          Winter
   CE          Summer
   CE          Winter
```

What is the SQL query to print the names and the semester where each student's department have only 1 type of semester?

```
SQL Query Result should be like this:
Name     Semester
Bob       Summer
Briyan    Winter
James     Summer
```

Here, CSE and CE have both summer and winter semester. So Alex, John and Mike are not included.

I have tried this far:

```
SELECT Student.Name,
     Program.Semester
FROM Student
JOIN Program
    ON Program.Department = Student.Department
WHERE ....
```

Comment: Is this sql server or mysql? You've tagged both, but one costs substantially more per core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to run a query like this (see db-fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kpvtHCTenj1PcgWrV5i358/8)):

```
SELECT 
  st.student_name, 
  -- st.student_dept,  -- <<= uncomment for an insight into
  -- sm.semester_dept, -- <<= how the query works!
  sm.semester_name
FROM student st
JOIN semester sm
ON
  st.student_dept = sm.semester_dept
WHERE st.student_dept IN
(
  SELECT
    sm.semester_dept AS sem_dept
  FROM semester sm
  GROUP BY sm.semester_dept
  HAVING COUNT(sm.semester_dept) = 1 
)
```

Result:

```
Student name  Semester name
___________________________
         Bob         Summer
      Briyan         Winter
       James         Summer
```

This query will work (I believe) for any/all of the major RDBMS servers - works on MySQL and (my reference implementation, PostgreSQL [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0f3f6/11)). Oh, yes, just a point to note - the `student_name` field should be a `PRIMARY KEY` (or at least `UNIQUE` with `NOT NULL`) in order for this to be guaranteed to work properly!

This solution is much more elegant than my original query solution ([here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kpvtHCTenj1PcgWrV5i358/8)) - thanks to @ypercube for the hint!

============== DDL and DML ==================

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
  student_name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
  student_dept VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO student VALUES
('Alex',   'CSE'),
('Bob' ,   'EEE'),
('Briyan', 'ME'),
('John',   'CSE'),
('James',  'ETE'),
('Mike',   'CE');

CREATE TABLE semester
(
  department VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL,
  semester   VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO semester VALUES
('CSE', 'Summer'),
('CSE', 'Winter'),
('EEE', 'Summer'),
('ETE', 'Summer'),
('ME',  'Winter'),
('CE',  'Summer'),
('CE',  'Winter');
```

Comment: You don't really need the derived table and the join: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kpvtHCTenj1PcgWrV5i358/4

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - thanks for the heads up on that! I'm doing a data visualisation course at the moment and it's amazing how our preconceived concepts can block us mentally to what appears afterwards to be glaringly obvious! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Building on [Vérace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/34007/v%c3%a9race)'s and [ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%e1%b5%80%e1%b4%b9)'s work, here is a variation that, while using both a join and a derived table, hits each underlying table only once:

```
SELECT
  st.student_name, 
  sm.semester_name
FROM
  student AS st
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      semester_dept,
      MIN(semester_name) AS semester_name
    FROM
      semester
    GROUP BY
      semester_dept
    HAVING
      COUNT(*) = 1 
  ) AS sm ON st.student_dept = sm.semester_dept
ORDER BY
  st.student_name
;
```

The derived table returns only the departments with a single semester. Basically, it is the original `semester` table without the departments having more than one semester. Once you have that data set, it only remains for you to join it to the `student` table to get the final output.

One could, of course, further simplify the above query like this:

```
SELECT
  st.student_name, 
  MIN(sm.semester_name) AS semester_name
FROM
  student st
  INNER JOIN semester sm ON st.student_dept = sm.semester_dept
GROUP BY
  st.student_name,
  sm.semester_dept
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 1 
ORDER BY
  st.student_name
;
```

Just a join, no derived table, simple and elegant. However, in terms of performance, the latter solution could be worse or much worse, depending on the DBMS you are running it in. The former option aggregates only a single table, which is much easier to optimise, particularly when you have proper indices defined. Aggregation across multiple tables, on the other hand, is trickier. The RDBMS might take into account explicitly defined foreign key relationships, if any, but that still would be unlikely to achieve the same efficiency as aggregating one table individually and only then joining the resulting set to other tables.

Perhaps, the last query could be slightly improved by replacing the `sm.semester_dept` column in the GROUP BY with `st.student_dept`, i.e. like this:

```
SELECT
  st.student_name, 
  MIN(sm.semester_name) AS semester_name
FROM
  student st
  INNER JOIN semester sm ON st.student_dept = sm.semester_dept
GROUP BY
  st.student_name,
  st.student_dept
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 1 
ORDER BY
  st.student_name
;
```

That would still be aggregating across multiple tables, but using only columns from the same table as grouping criteria might make the resulting query more efficient.

All three options are available in a [live demo at *dbfiddle.uk*](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=2744ece4bf1418086f4ae47e0beb95ec).